# PHP: Does empty() validate all of these cases: null, empty string, variable not set?

Tags: php

Does empty() function validate all of this cases:

1.var=null

2.var=empty string ""/"   "

3.var=not set

**Example for validate use (Should I add some more code for validation or empty() enough?):**

```
if(!empty($userName)){
  //some code
}

else{
  echo "not valid user name"
}
```

---

***Edit***: should `isset()` used before `empty()` or `empty()` includes the `isset()` case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the following i would say it fits your needs:

> The following things are considered
>   to be empty:
>
> ```
> * "" (an empty string)
> * 0 (0 as an integer)
> * "0" (0 as a string)
> * NULL
> * FALSE
> * array() (an empty array)
> * var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
> ```

*EDIT:*

> should isset() used before empty() or
>   empty() include isset() case?

This depends on the usage. IF you are in a  position where you cant be sure `$username` exists then you need to use isset first to avoid an error about a nonexistent variable. If on the other hand you are sure `$username` will always exist then you can jsut test for the empty value and leave it at that.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it does. It's in the [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the user has filled in *anything at all* then empty() is ok. If you, on the other hand, want to check if the user filled in a username longer than 3 chars (strlen()) or only with alphanumeric chars (preg_match()) you will need some more tools ;)